# How would I sort file using Tcl according to size of those files?

Tags: file, sorting, tcl

I have a list of files and a separate list of sizes of those files using "file size <file_name>".

I am required to sort the files in ascending order based on the size and then feed it further for processing.

Can someone provide a step by step process I could follow?

This is what I have done so far

```
set direc "<Any direcotry to look files at>"
set folderFiles [glob -directory $direc -nocomplain -type f *.xml]
set fileSizes []

puts "Files to be processed are:"
puts "$folderFiles"

puts "Sizes of files in this order are:"
foreach tempFile $folderFiles {
    lappend fileSizes [file size $tempFile]
}
puts $fileSizes

set fileDict [dict create [lindex $folderFiles 0] [lindex $fileSizes 0]]
for {set i 1} {$i < [llength $folderFiles]} {incr i} {
    dict lappend fileDict [lindex $folderFiles $i] [lindex $fileSizes $i]
}

puts $fileDict
```

So, this gives me a dictionary where keys -> files and values -> file sizes. I just need to sort this dictionary based on values which are file sizes.

Comment: It's considered good practice to try something out, then come to SO with problems with what you tried. This comes off as a "write the code for me" request, which is borderline rude. (Hint: read documentation for `lsort`)

Comment: @Andreas I am new to StackOverflow. Anyway, I had put effort. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to get the list of filenames and their sizes. You can keep the sizes separately.

```
set filenames [glob -type f *.foo]; # Or whatever
set sizes [lmap f $filenames {file size $f}]
```

Then we sort the sizes, but get the *indices* of the sort back rather than the sorted list.

```
set indices [lsort -indices -integer $sizes]
```

Now, we use those indices to construct the sorted filenames:

```
set filenames [lmap idx $indices {lindex $filenames $idx}]
```

We can combine some of these things into a helper procedure:

```
proc SortFilesBySize {filenames} {
    set sizes [lmap f $filenames {file size $f}]
    return [lmap idx [lsort -indices -integer $sizes] {lindex $filenames $idx}]
}

set filenames [glob -type f *.foo]; # Or whatever
puts [join [SortFilesBySize $filenames] "\n"]
```

Comment: Note that getting the size of files is comparatively expensive as it involves filesystem access; that means that while it is possible to use a custom comparator that uses `file size` each time, it's a slow method, especially with lots of files. By contrast, approaches that fetch the size of each file only once are much faster in practice.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc zip {list1 list2} {
    lmap a $list1 b $list2 { list $a $b }
}

proc heads {pairs} {
    lmap pair $pairs { lindex $pair 0 }
}

proc sort_by_size {names sizes} {
    heads [lsort -integer -increasing -index 1 [zip $names $sizes]]
}

set names {a.txt b.txt c.txt}
set sizes {3 2 1}
puts [sort_by_size $names $sizes]
```

Combines the names and sizes into a list of pairs of filename and size, sorts based on size, and then returns just the reordered filenames. Essentially a `tcl` version of `perl`'s classic [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) idiom.